# My textures turn purple in the render

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

When I start rendering my animation (a cube rotating in front of a background), at some frames, my textures turn purple (not fully, mostly just the white parts). I know this is a sign of misisng textures, but in some frames they work.

[image: My setup]
[image]
[Here's the finished render.](https://streamable.com/izjeca)
It looks like if a strong purple light has been added.
If anyone knows, what's the problem, please help me!
(I tried reopening the textures, didn't work.)

Comment: If it is working fine for some of the frames, consider to report a Bug *Main menu > Help > Report a Bug*. Otherwise add more information and preferably a blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to your question.

Comment: @brockmann ok, added the file

Comment: (It might terribly obvious, I'm not super good with Blender)

Comment: The textures are missing, may be you moved the file and Blender doesn't find the pictures.

Comment: Solved it, needed to set world properties to use nodes